# Seaborn Show Number of Observations in each Panel

Tags: python, seaborn

The following code produces the following output.

```py
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.displot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", y="bill_length_mm", col="species", row="sex")
```

[image: img]

I'd like to know how many observations (N) were used in each panel and I'd like to show them inside each panel, if possible. Does somebody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`g.map_dataframe(func)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe.html) where `func` is user defined and receives two parameters: a color (to allow a consistent coloring) and `data`, the subset of the dataframe used for this subplot. Each time `func` is called, matplotlib's "current ax" will be set to a specific subplot. `plt.gca()` gets access to that `ax`.

Here is an example adding the length of the subset via ["axes coordinates"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def show_counts(color, data):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0.5, 0.95, f'Count: {len(data)}', ha='center', color=color, transform=ax.transAxes)

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.displot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", y="bill_length_mm", col="species", row="sex")
g.map_dataframe(show_counts)
plt.show()
```

[image: adding text to displot]

Comment: Wow, this is a very nice and elegant solution. Thank you!